# How to get info of whitelisted Vimeo video via API?

Tags: vimeo-api

Vimeo allows users (pro only feature?) to set the video to be "whitelisted": they will only play when embedded in certain website. Technically, it is implemented by checking the `referer` header.

I was wondering if it's possible to get info of such info via API (when referer whitelist is known).

Keep in mind I'm talking about video uploaded by *others*, not account which API is authorized in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data is not available in the API.